# Extract stuff between the first pipes in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to extract the stuff in between the first two pipes:

```
| a650f360-a29d-4562-b46f-024fe15aa7dc | emi-ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64-08152013           | ACTIVE |
```

The output should be:

```
 a650f360-a29d-4562-b46f-024fe15aa7dc
```

I have a regex that I was going to use sed with: `^\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|`

but according to a regex calculator it gets me the pipes as well. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/^[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|.*/\1/'
```

That matches any non-pipes at the beginning (nothing in the example data), a pipe, captures the stuff that isn't a pipe, matches another pipe and anything at the end, and replaces it with the captured stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Cut is probably easier to understand than regex. Why not

```
cut -d\| -f2
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Bash only. In a loop this can be done using an array:

```
while IFS='|'; read -a line ; do
  echo ${line[1]}            # with leading/trailing blanks
  echo ${line[1]// /}        # without leading/trailing blanks
done < "$infile"
```

Comment: Or portably `while IFS='|' read -r _ value _; do echo "$value"; done` or more generally supply as many variables as you need to `read`; it will tokenize the input until only one variable remains, then assign the rest of the input to the last variable.  So to get the fifth field, `read -r _ _ _ _ this _; ... echo "$this"`,  Conventionally, the variable name `_` is used in this context to identify variables you read but don't really care about.  (Arrays are a Bash feature, while this approach is portable to any POSIX shell.)

Comment: You should use `read -r` because the default behavior of `read` is to do weird stuff with input containing e.g. backslashes.